# Can I retrieve nesting level of term without navigating all parents?

Tags: csom, term

I'm retrieving `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.Term` by Guid. It has `Parent` property, which can have `Parent` property, etc.

Can I find out, which nesting level is specific term, without recursively calling `Load()` and the expensive `ExecuteQuery()` on each Parent?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is exactly usable in your situation, but maybe it helps:

In PowerShell you can use the *GetPath()* method and count the semicolons.
Example:

*Root
      \- Child*

*GetPath()* used on 'Child' returns *'Root;Child'* - so the nesting level is the count of the ';'.

Additionally there is the *'isRoot'* property to quickly check if it is a toplevel term.